# Is it possible to retrieve the email address of the recipient in facebook messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating a FB messenger bot and I'm fetching the recipient's user details using the following Graph Api call - "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/USER-ID?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender,is_payment_enabled,email&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"

However, the response doesn't include the email field. The value is always null. I am able to get all other fields. Can someone explain me the steps I should follow to retrieve the email of the recipient?

Is there any explicit permission needed for the bot? In that case, kindly help me out with the steps needed to enable the permission.

Comment: Did the user grant you user_email permission?

Comment: I am not sure if I have granted it. Can you suggest me the steps to grant the permission?

Comment: The e-mail is deliberately not part of the info you can get purely based on that the user is chatting to your page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile#fields If you want anything more than what is listed there, then you need to use Account Linking to make them log in to your app and grant it permission first, so that you can afterwards request these additional details via Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking the user for permission to see their email, you could prompt for it with quick replies, which is more likely the user will end up giving you their email, than actually accepting the permission to access the email in their profile.

Take a look at [prompting for the email using quick replies on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies#email). You can also prompt for phone number, location, and show the regular text suggestions. You can even mix them up in the same prompt.

[image]